# Continuity of $f$ and monotone decreasing of $g(x) = \cos(f(x))$ implies uniform continuity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I want to show uniformly continuity of $f$ under

$f$ is continuous and $f(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $g(x) = \cos(f(x))$ is monotonically decreasing.

---

I know if $f$ is differentiable and $|f'|$ is bounded then $f$ is uniformly continuous. And from $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing if $g$ is differentiable, then naively I can guess $g'(x) <0$ (decreasing) and deduce $g'(x) = - f'(x) \sin(f(x))<0$,  ...

But the information given here is not enough to show $g$ and $f$ are differentiable.

Comment: Your function has to be monotone increasing (by properties of $\cos$) and bounded (by $\pi$.) Now use [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550155/prove-that-a-bounded-monotone-increasing-and-continuous-function-is-uniformly)

Comment: For uniformly continuity we need existence of finite $\lim \cos(f(x))$ on infinities.